# Select data atual

Tags: php, sql-server

Preciso de um `select` que puxe todos registros da tabela da data atual(hoje), sem informar a data, no sql-server e como ficaria a sintaxe em PHP também. Sendo que possuo uma coluna chamada **DtBase** que armazena as datas dos registros.

Comment: opa tenta DtBase = GETDATE();

Comment: Ta, blz e no php eu uso esse getdate(); no sql também ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin,

Uma solução em SQL seria

```
select * from Tabela where convert(date, DtBase) = convert(date, getdate())
```

Uso a função `convert` para casos em que é armazenada a hora junto da data, então tem que fazer essa conversão.

Agora como fazer em PHP não sei, pois não trabalho com essa linguagem de programação

Comment: Certo, atendeu o que eu precisava só faltou php mas é o do menos.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, se entendi bem sua pergunta você quer dar um select em todos os registros da tabela onde a data no campo DtBase seja igual a do dia de hoje, se você puder inserir a data,

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE DtBase='2016-03-14';
```

Se você não puder inserir a data e quer sempre a do dia pode tentar a função CURDATE() do sqlServer, não tenho certeza se funcionaria pois já tem algum tempo que só trabalho com Oracle...

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE DtBase=CURDATE();
```

Comment: o que ele quer é Sql-Server.

Answer (score -1):

Se a data em seu banco de dados esta armazenada no formato "2016-03-14 09:26:18" você pode procurar diretamente no SQLServer com o comando:

```MySQL
select * from TableName where DtBase like '%2016-03-14%';
```

em PHP algo como:

```PHP
$data = date("Y-m-d");
$busca = "FROM `TableName` WHERE `DtBase` LIKE '%".data."%'";
```

Comment: ops..., desculpe

Comment: like em campo date /datetime?

Comment: Sim, pois dependendo de como a data é salva no banco ela pode estar no formato "2016-03-14 17:14:35".

Então, usando o LIKE no campo date/datetime eu filtro por todos os horários da data desejada.

Como não foi especificado de que forma as datas foram inseridas no banco, dei o exemplo usando o LIKE.

Espero que tenha sido claro em minha resposta.